# Bash script for starting jenkins node don't start as linux service in CentOS when it's boot up

Tags: bash, service, centos, jnlp

i was written bash script which will start slave.jar process and vm will appear in jenkins. I have to start this script as service when linux boot up. I place my file in etc/init.d, with chmod +x and after that make chckconfig on it and all links are appears in rc.d folders, output of chkconfig shows:

```
 jenkins-slave   0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

When i make reboot nothing happend, when i run via sudo service jenkins-slave start everything is ok. All propertis contains in another file, everything is working when make it by hands in open session.  How to make it auto executable when CentOs 6 up?

my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# jenkins-slave:    Launch a Jenkins BuildSlave instance on this node
#
# chkconfig:    - 99 01
# description:  Enable this node to fulfill build jobs
#

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/jenkins-slave ] && . /etc/sysconfig/jenkins-slave

[ -n "$JENKINS_URL" ] || exit 0
[ -n "$JENKINS_WORKDIR" ] || exit 0
[ -n "$JENKINS_USER" ] || exit 0
[ -n "$JENKINS_NODENAME" ] || exit 0
[ -x /usr/bin/java ] || exit 0

download_jar()
{
curl -s -o slave.jar $JENKINS_URL/jnlpJars/slave.jar || exit 0
}

start()
{
cd $JENKINS_WORKDIR
[ -f slave.jar ] || download_jar

    echo -n $"Starting Jenkins BuildSlave: "
    su - $JENKINS_USER sh -c "\
  java -jar slave.jar \
         -jnlpUrl $JENKINS_URL/computer/$JENKINS_NODENAME/slave-agent.jnlp \
         >slave.log 2>&1 &"

    echo Done.
}

stop()
{
    echo -n $"Shutting down Jenkins BuildSlave: "
killproc slave.jar

    echo Done.
}

# See how we were called.
case "$1" in
 start)
  start
    ;;
stop)
 stop
    ;;
restart|reload)
 stop
  start
;;
 status)
  status java
  ;;
 *)
    echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|reload}"
    exit 1
 esac

  exit 0
```

Comment: have you checked the permissions for your service ? http://superuser.com/questions/472219/linux-permissions-for-services

Comment: Does the service script work when run as `/etc/init.d/jenkins-slave` manually? Does it work if you run `/bin/sh /etc/init.d/jenkins-slave`? If you add `set -x` to the top of the script what do you see as output when you reboot?